# RegularExpression to match word in plural preceded by numbers

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

`20 mins`

I would like to create a RegularExpression in PHP that is capable of finding such a string using `preg_match()`. The Expression should be sufficiently dynamic so that it will recognize non-plurals and more options for the preceding numeric values. For example, the following examples should also be matched:

- `1 min`
- `0.5 mins`
- `999 mins`

I have tried with the following, but it doesn't execute:

```
(^|\b)[0-99999*]\/b\min[s]?\b
```

Comment: If I may ask, what are these: `(^|\b)`? `[0-99999*]`? `\/b`?? `\m`? It's probably easier to write each part on its own, and see if it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this pattern:

```
\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\smins?\b
```

note: you can allow more than one space between the number and "mins" replacing `\s` by `\s+`

note2: a character class is a bag with characters, writing `[0-99999*]` has no sense. [See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? mins?\b
```

It should match all cases you want including these:

```
•1 min
•0.5 mins
•999 mins
•0.51213123 mins
•2352352.51213123 mins
```